# C++. Наследование. Как сделать статический метод возвращающий оба типа?

Tags: c++, объекты, наследование, статические-члены

Есть класс-предок и его класс-потомок. Надо чтобы у них обоих были методы с одинаковым названием, принимающие строку и в зависимости от того с какого слова она начинается возвращали либо экземпляр предка, либо экземплер потомка. Подскажите синтаксис. Там вроде как-то возвращать указатель на предка надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экземпляр вернуть нельзя, можно вернуть только указатель.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
    static Parent* test(const std::string& in) 
    {
         return new Parent();
    };
};


class Child:public Parent
{
public:
    static Parent* test(const std::string& in)
    {
          return new Child(); //здесь неявно будет приведет тип указателя
    };
};
```

*Замечание:*

Виртуальный деструктор у родителя нужен практически всегда, когда речь идет о наследовани - иначе при удалении, не будет вызыаться деструктор наследника, что приведет как минимум к утечке ресурсов.

Comment: а что делать если я хочу не обычный указатель, а unique_ptr?

Comment: Возвращать unique_ptr на родителя. А что не работает?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AndreyKom/e1f53fcff8e84f892790107f8fbd80e6
вот эта штука если попадает в иф для дочернего класса возвращает родительский и поэтому нельзя обратиться к полю впервые определенному в дочернем классе

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov я ж написал - нужно возвращать unique_ptr на родителя, а вы упорно конструируете указатель на потомка

Comment: а как его возвращать-то? если кастовать перед ретёрном - это то же самое, а если просто заменить шаблонный параметр в make_unique конструктор не подойдет.

Comment: return unique_ptr<Parent>(new Child());

Comment: у меня это дает то же самое (не видит поле)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119738/discussion-between-gbg-and-andrey-komisarov).